# How to take the value selected in a dropdown?

Tags: gradio

I am working with Gradio to integrate with my own module EDA (short of exploratory data analysis).

What I have been trying to is once the user selects a feature to update the target in my module and consequently in the gr.Textbox to update the value to "eda.introductory_results()" which displays a dict with information about the dataset.

I tried to create a function to update the values but when I run the demo and change the values nothing seems to happen.

(Side notes: my module EDA has a method called new_target to update the target which by default is None).

```
eda = EDA(df=df, target=None)

def update_target_and_textbox(selected_value):
    print(selected_value)
    eda.new_target(new_target=selected_value)
    resultados_eda.value = eda.introductory_results()

# Gradio interface
with gr.Blocks(css="Gradio/styles.css", title="0Accidentes") as demo:
    gr.Markdown("""![](file/Gradio/logo_lis.svg) 0Accidentes""", elem_classes="cabecero")

    with gr.Tab("EDA"):
        with gr.Row():
            with gr.Column(scale=1):
                variable_objetivo = gr.Dropdown(label="Variable Objetivo", choices=sorted(list(df.columns)))

                variable_objetivo.change(update_target_and_textbox, inputs=variable_objetivo, outputs=variable_objetivo.value)
```